# Until convergence using for loop? (Newton's)

Tags: matlab, newtons-method

It is obvious while loop is easily used for running until convergence (Newton's), but is it possible to use a for loop?

while loop for reference:

```
maxIteration = 1000
tol = % some small number

while (n>0)
  % do something

  if n<tol % converges
    return;
  end;

  if n>maxIteration % diverges
    break;
  end;
end;
```

(don't mind syntax)

Comment: I guess return and break works for for loops as well. If anyone has other suggestions please post

Comment: Nope, you got it.  If you know how to use `break` and `if` statements, you should be able to figure out how to treat `for` loops like `while` loops (and vice versa).  Though I will say that I haven't used a `for` loop with iterative methods in years; I think `while` loops are semantically superior.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the line

```
for n = 1:maxIteration
    % Do something

    % Converges
    if error < tol
        return;
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for answering. By the way, do you by any chance know the syntax for evaluating multiple variables? like f(x,y) f is some vector such as [x^2 y^3] values = [1 2] and should return ans = [1 8]

Comment: You can directly evaluate vectors with other vectors of the same size, just try it. i.e. 
a = [5 5]
b = [4 6]
a>b   % returns vector [1 0]   (true, false)